# What are some good online forums for discussing photographic editing?

Tags: photoshop, image-quality, tutorial, photo-galleries

What are some good forums for talking about editing photos in Photoshop or GIMP? Where do you talk about such things?

**EDIT:** Other than here, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completely agree with jrista, but assuming you meant "other than this cool place", I like dgrin's "[Finishing School](http://www.dgrin.com/forumdisplay.php?s=d904174bf137575d3d4e3a75f394815e&f=10)" subforum.

Comment: Hm, that looks good indeed. :)

Answer (score 12):

Well, I would recommend this site first. ;) Discussing the editing and post-processing of photos is one of the primary purposes of this site, and as a strong support here, I can't help but promote it. It may be rather slim right now, but given the overall success of StackExchange sites, I do not doubt that this site can become one of, if not the, top resource on the Internet for photography and photographic editing questions.

Comment: Especially since the software is so much better than typical forum software. If the community and content can rise to the level of quality of the software and keep growing, I'd be shocked if it doesn't turn up top answers in Google all the time, a year from now. Wow this is getting Meta-ish.

Answer (score 4):

For starters I would visit: 
 - [Adobe Photoshop forum](http://forums.adobe.com/community/photoshop) 
 - [Gimp forum](http://www.gimptalk.com/forum/)

But, +1 for @jrista's suggestion... this is the spot :)